# Prove $a^3b + b^3c + c^3a \geq a^2b^2 + b^2c^2 + a^2c^2$

Tags: inequality, contest-math

> Prove $a^3b + b^3c + c^3a \geq a^2b^2 + b^2c^2 + a^2c^2$, where $a \geq b \geq c > 0$.

This is a problem from [Algebraic Inequalities](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-77836-5).

I found a similar problem [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/438488/prove-that-a3b3c3-geq-a2bb2cc2a).

Using the AM-GM inequality, I got $a^3 b + a ^ 3 b + b^ 4 \geq 3 a^ 2 b^2$.

And consequently, I obtained $\frac{2}{3} (a^3b + b^3c + c^3a) + \frac{1}{3} (a^4 + b^4 + c^4) \geq a^2b^2 + b^2c^2 + a^2c^2$.

However, I still cannot solve it.

If anyone has a nice solution, please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please check Approach zero's search result, https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24a%5E3b%20%2B%20b%5E3c%20%2B%20c%5E3a%20%5Cgeq%20a%5E2b%5E2%20%2B%20b%5E2c%5E2%20%2B%20a%5E2c%5E2%24&p=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $b=c+x, a=b+y=c+x+y
$
where
$c, x, y \ge 0$.

$\begin{array}\\
d
&=a^3b + b^3c + c^3a - (a^2b^2 + b^2c^2 + a^2c^2)\\
&=a^3b-a^2b^2 + b^3c-b^2c^2 + c^3a - a^2c^2\\
&=a^2b(a-b)+ b^2c(b-c) + c^2a(c-a)\\
&=(c+x+y)^2(c+x)y+ (c+x)^2cx - c^2(c+x+y)(x+y)\\
&=c^2 x^2 + c^2 x y + c^2 y^2 + c x^3 + 3 c x^2 y + 4 c x y^2 + c y^3 + x^3 y + 2 x^2 y^2 + x y^3\\
&\ge 0
\qquad\text{since all the terms are } \ge 0\\
\end{array}
$

with the expansion
done by Wolfram Alpha.

Answer (score 0):

One can use multiplicative change of variables as well. Write $ a = \alpha c, \; b = \beta c $ where $ \alpha \geq \beta \geq 1 $.
We need to see that $ \alpha^3 \beta  + \beta^3 + \alpha\geq \alpha^2 \beta^2 
+ \alpha^2 + \beta^2 $. Setting $ \alpha = r \beta $ where $  r \geq   1$ this turns into $ r^3 \beta^4 + \beta^3 + r \beta \geq r^2 \beta^4 + r^2 \beta^2 + \beta^2$. Dividing by $\beta$ we get $ r^3 \beta^3 + \beta^2 + r \geq r^2 \beta^3 + 
r^2 \beta + \beta,  \;\; \; \beta,r \geq 1$. For $ \beta $ fixed, both sides are functions of r, say $ f(r),g(r)$. Further, $ f(1) = \beta^3 + \beta^2 + 1 \geq g(1) = \beta^3 + 2 \beta  $. To verify the inequality for all $ r \geq 1 $ it is sufficient to show that $ f'(r) \geq g'(r) $ for all
$ r \geq 1 $. That is we have to show that $ f'(r) = 3 \beta^3 r^2 + 1 \geq
2 r (\beta^3 + \beta) = g'(r) $ for all $ \beta, r \geq 1$. When $ r = 1$ we have $ f'(1) = 3\beta^3 + 1 \geq  2\beta^3 + 2\beta = g'(1) $ that is correct for all $ \beta \geq 1 $ (because $\beta^3 - 2\beta + 1 \geq \beta^2 - 2\beta + 1 \geq 0 $). Using rhe same trick again, note that it is sufficient to see that $ f''(r) = 6 \beta^3 r \geq  2\beta^3 + 2\beta = g''(r) $ for all $ \beta, r \geq 1$, but this obvious.